# Public/Private keys for encryption of data

Tags: encryption

I am building an app that uses encryption.

The issue is that I'm not familiar with the best approach to store a private key.

Lets begin with an example:

Messaging apps that have end-to-end encryption, so the sender uses the public key of the receiver to encrypt data and the receiver uses its private key to decrypt it. Right?

But what is the approach to storing this private key?
I mean, if I store this key in a database it is as good as nothing, if my database get hacked then all the private keys are exposed.

Also, if I store the key on the device, there is also the possibility of someone finding the key and owning it.

My question is, what do I do with the private key?

What is the current approach to this problem?

For example, how does telegram stores its user keys securely?

Comment: `My question is, what do I do with the private key?` Do you mean on a mobile device?

Comment: @gusto2 Yes! I'm building a mobile app!

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, what do I do with the private key?

You can encrypt the priv key using the [Android Keystore System](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data) MasterKey, which may request authentication (biometric, device pattern, pin) upon decryption.

```
KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameterSpec = MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC;
String mainKeyAlias = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(keyGenParameterSpec);
```

iOS has similar mechanism, but you have to search it yourself